# a problem about priority queue use decltype and lambda to custom comparator

Tags: c++, priority-queue

my project outline is:
project
include
a.h
node.h
src
a.cpp
test
main.cpp
In node.h:

```
class node
{
}
auto cmp = [](const node* a,const node* b)
{
};
```

In a.h:

```
#include"node.h"
class plane
{
public:
    void getNeighborNode(std::priority_queue<node*, std::vector<node*>, decltype(cmp)> & neighbors);
}
```

In a.cpp:

```
#include"a.h"
void plane::getNeighborNode(std::priority_queue<node*, std::vector<node*>, decltype(cmp) > & neighbors)
{

}
```

In main.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
std::priority_queue<node*, std::vector<node*>, decltype(cmp) >  neighbors(cmp);
tmpplane.getNeighborNode(neighbors);
```

the error is:

> undefined reference to
> `plane::getNeighborNode(std::priority_queue<node*, std::vector<node*,
> std::allocator<node*> >, quatree::{lambda(node const*, node
> const*)#1}>&)

I have add a.cpp to the CMakeLists.txt.

but when I change the comparator to

```
struct compnode
{
  bool operator() (node* a, node* b) 
  {
    
  }
};
```

it will be ok.

I do not know what is the problem?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. What is `tmpplane`? How does the comparator involve the undefined reference? You did not add a.cpp to build, then added and solved the error.

Comment: tmpplane is an object of class plane. I have add a.cpp to build. when I use `struct compnode` as a comparator , the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You are violating the one-definition-rule by having two definitions for `cmp` (because you include the header in two translation units). Therefore your program is *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*.

You cannot use a lambda like this. Write a proper (inline) function instead:

```
inline auto cmp(const node* a,const node* b)
{
};
```

Alternatively you can declare `cmp` as `inline constexpr` since C++17.

Comment: Thanks for you answer my question. I have test your answer but the problem is not solved.